# Show list buttons when user clicks on Go to list link

Tags: related-list, button

How to show list buttons when user clicks on Go to list link in related list.I see there is a [**idea**](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq2t) posted. Any work around for this.

[image]